# Reference Request: Kunen Line

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, set-theory

I'm looking for a reference to the definition and properties of the Kunen Line. I am unable to find it in the index of $\textit{Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology}$ although I vaguely remember seeing it there, and the same is true with Jech's $\textit{Set Theory}$. Google is also returning no helpful results.

Edit: Found here

I. Juhász, K. Kunen, M.E. Rudin, [Two more hereditarily separable non-Lindelöf spaces](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-journal-of-mathematics/article/two-more-hereditarily-separable-nonlindelof-spaces/4EB35BCA02ABC9EC544894CDE004BF48), Canad. J. Math. 28 (1976) 998–1005

Comment: Juhasz' survey paper [*Ken Kunen, the set-theoretic topologist*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166864111003713?via%3Dihub) may be of interest.

Comment: Yep, found the reference. Thanks a ton as always.